# How to Wait in While Loop till Loop is Asked to be Continued in Swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, dispatch-queue

I want to make Network Requests inside a while loop and check if the result satisfies a condition. If condition is not satisfied, I want to continue running the while loop and again make Network Request and so on..

What I am trying to do is:
Pseudo code:

```
while true{
  // Run Network Req and get Result
  // Check a Condition using Result
  // If Condition is met: return using completion Handler
  // If Condition is not met, continue with the While loop
}
```

My try:

```
while true{
  // Run Network Req and get Result
  request(){ response in
    switch response{
      case .success (let res){
        // Check a Condition using Result
        if(res.count == 10){
          // If Condition is met: return using completion Handler
          completionHandler(res)
        }
        else{
           // If Condition is not met, continue with the While loop
         **// 1. HOW TO CONTINUE THE LOOP?**
        }
      }

      case .failure{
        completionHandler(error)
      }
    }
  }
  **// 2. HOW TO WAIT TILL LOOP IS CONTINUED?**
}
```

Comment: use dispatch group.

Comment: Don’t wait, never wait. And those `while` loops are pointless in an asynchronous environment. Use Swift Concurrency, it provides all ways to load data asynchronously in a synchronous manner but without blocking the thread(s).

Comment: @RajaKishan Can you elaborate with an example please?

Comment: @vadian it's a usecase in project.